# How to find the lowest number in an Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, integer, associative-array, min

This is the problem:

I have the following array (from `$wpdb->get_results()`):

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(7) "1102006"
    }
    [1]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(7) "1102006"
    }
    [2]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(7) "8092007"
    }
    [3]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "23062012"
    }
    [4]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "29072000"
    }
    [5]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "30082008"
    }
}
```

And I would like to find the lowest integer from 10,000 on that is NOT in this array. In this case the answer would be 10,000 as 10,000 is not in the array.

Thanks

Comment: The answer would always be 10000 unless you plan to append the result of this function to that array. Is that the case?

Comment: The answer is 10,000 at step 1. As a consequence of this, the user can choose the default 10,000 or another number he/she prefers. Then at step 2, another user will face the same decision and so on and so forth.. My problem is, that I do not know how to 'say' to the algorithm to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I interpreted your question.

Starting from 10000, find the first available number that is NOT within your data array.

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array('1102006'),
    array('1102006'),
    array('8092007'),
    array('23062012'),
    array('29072000'),
    array('30082008')
);

// flatten the array to a single dimension
function flatten(&$v) { $v = $v[0]; }

array_walk($data, 'flatten');

// minimum number
$num = 10000;

// while a value has not been found
while (!isset($value))
{
    // check if the current number is in our data (exclusion list)
    if (array_search($num, $data) === false)
        $value = $num;

    // increment for our next search
    $num++;
}

echo $value;
```

If you are just after the minimum value in that array, flatten the array in the previous answer and use `min`:

```
echo min($data);
```

Comment: Hi Alex, from what I read, this is very close to what I am looking for! Unfortunately, I can test it as I get an error message when I run array_walk.. I am using PHP 5.2.6, I do not know if this can explain the error..